# Silverlight HttpWebRequest Fails to include .ASPXAUTH Cookie in Header

Tags: silverlight, cookies, httpwebrequest

Right now I have a silverlight app that gets data from a mvc site. As long as I use WebClient and to GET requests, everything seems to be okay. However, when I use HttpWebRequest and POST, then I am getting authentication problems.

The problems stem from the request lacking the .ASPXAUTH cookie.

Does anyone know how to solve or work around this?

Comment: you want to pass .ASPXAUTH in the header of httpRequest?

Comment: It must be passed. Otherwise the resource won't return the data. According to what I have read of the documentation, it is supposed to do that automatically. And that is what it does when I use WebClient. However, I must use HttpWebRequest for POST.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

write following code before making `HttpWebRequest` object.

> System.Net.WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp);
>                           System.Net.WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("https://", WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp);

and then create the HttpWebRequest object.

> // Create request
>   HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("http://zainshaikh.posterous.com/");

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check the code.  I will test and give feedback on it.

Comment: That was it. Thanks! :) You just made me and a project manager very happy :)

Answer (score 1):

I recently got bit by this too. You're hitting the separation of brower-based communication and Silverlight-based communication. When you use WebClient, you're actually making the request through the browser's HTTP stack, and therefore get all of the automatic cookie handling. When you use HttpWebRequest, you're using Silverlight's HTTP stack, and therefore cannot use the cookies sent to the browser; the two cookie stores are separate. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838250%28VS.95%29.aspx) for more details.

I was writing out @Zain's answer, which registers the HttpWebRequest with the browser's HTTP stack and works around the issue, but he beat me to it ;-).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will read it carefully. In a link I read for Silverlight 2, it said that both WebClient and HttpWebRequest were using the browswer stack. I guess that must have changed in 3 or 4.

Comment: consider voting up my answer if you like :)